# Can anyone provide me with a list of English words that are their own antonyms?

Tags: list-request, antonyms

I am looking for a list of all English words that are their own antonyms. Off the top of my head, I can only think of "either", "fast", "to dust" and "to lease", but there must be dozens more. Can you provide a link to a comprehensive list, if such exists?

Also, what are such words most commonly called? I like the term "Janus word" I once heard, but is that widely understood?

<sup><sub>Edited by popular demand to make it absolutely clear that this is not a community wiki poll.</sub></sup>

Comment: @RegDwight: BTW, the Wikipedia list can also *lose* entries over time, or get deleted. :-) There are some people who go around on Wikipedia trying to get such lists deleted as "unencyclopedic" (mostly unsuccessfully so far).

Comment: Is Contradictanym synonym to Auto-antonym? Can the term self-antonym be used?

Comment: I'm not sure if "ciao" and "aloha" have been noted yet, so I just wanted to make sure that they were. Each can be used both in greeting and farewell.

Comment: "cleave" is the first one that comes to mind, coming up in the text of certain wedding ceremonies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 1. It asks for a list. 2. It should be split into multiple questions- (of course the list part would still be off topic, but the "what is the name for this type of word" part is perfectly valid.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you're referring to [Auto-antonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym). They are not the same word but a homograph (a word of the same spelling) that is also an antonym. I guess, Janus word is also acceptable.

There was a list on Wikipedia ([List of Auto-antonyms in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_auto-antonyms_in_English&oldid=386138047)), since moved to Wiktionary's [Appendix of English contranyms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_contranyms).

Comment: Yet another piece of weirdness on Wikipedia, apparently "bolt" means "fixed", etc.

Comment: "Bolt" as a verb can mean "to run away" or "to fix in place (using a bolt)".

Comment: And I just came across this [nice cartoon](http://www.qwantz.com/index.php?comic=1104) featuring candid dinosaurs.

Comment: @Alexc I recall a photo (in Mad Magazine?) many decades ago, of a guy being told "Don't bolt your food!" - He was, of course, doing it with a wrench.

Comment: Also in the list of auto-antonyms, they forgot to include the dash, which can mean "add" (e.g., the shopping list note, "buy candy - chocolate bars, and suckers") or "subtract" (e.g., "5 - 3 = 2").

Comment: Also in the list of auto-antonyms, they forgot to include "fall", which can mean "occur" (as in "Tell where the stress falls in each of the following words.") and "tend toward non-occurrence" (as in "The world-wide popularity of French has greatly fallen in the past two hundred years.")

Comment: Also in the list of auto-antonyms, they forgot to include "lock in". For example, the police might lock a suspect in a cell, but, on the other hand, when I leave my family in the morning to go to work, I lock them in, not in the sense that they can't get out, but in the sense that an intruder can't get in.

Comment: Also in the list of auto-antonyms, they forgot to include "after", since it is sometimes used as an abbreviation for “afterwards”, which has the opposite meaning, as in the conundrum, “Charles I walked and talked a half hour after he was beheaded.”

Answer (score 5):

There are several names for these. "Contradictanym" is one you see in a few places. There's another list of several examples here: http://toothycat.net/wiki/wiki.pl?Contradictanym

Comment: What is the opposite of a Contradictanym? A word that doesn't contradict itself?

Answer (score 3):

Another word for it is ‘contranym’. Two types can be distinguished. There are those known as doublets, which have a common etymology, such as ‘fast’. Then there are those which are quite separate words that happen to be spelt the same way, such as ‘cleave’.