# "Tabled", US vs UK

Tags: etymology, verbs, american-english, british-english, ambiguity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of the expression “We can table this”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16285/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-expression-we-can-table-this)

Here's an example snippet for some context.

> Ann had an idea.  We tabled her idea.

In the UK this means "We put this idea on an agenda so it could be discussed".  In the US this seems to mean "We didn't have time, so we didn't put it on an agenda now.  We might sometime in the future."

These are different (sometimes opposite!) meanings.

What's the etymology of these usages for each country?

Comment: It means a little more than what you say it does in the U.S. Here it means we put off discussion of a topic *for whatever reason*, but usually because we don't see that it is possible to reach an agreement now — not enough interested parties are present, perhaps, or disagreement is too strong among the parties, or even, as you say, that there isn't enough time.

Comment: **table (v.)** in parliamentary sense, 1718, originally "to lay on the (speaker's) table for discussion," from **table** (n.). But in U.S. political jargon it has the sense of "to postpone indefinitely" (1866). Related: *Tabled*; *tabling*. —Online Etymology Dictionary

Comment: Both come from the metaphor of "putting (a document) on the table".  The difference in usage comes from *which* table: the discussion table, or the non-discussion table :)

Answer (score 5):

Under definition 4 of the verb *table*, the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/196786?rskey=USe7Xs&result=2#eid) gives two meanings. The first is ‘To present or submit formally for discussion or consideration. (Common in English-speaking regions outside the United States.)' The earliest citation supporting this use is from 1653.

The second meaning is ‘originally and chiefly U.S. To postpone consideration of, especially indefinitely; to shelve.’ The earliest citation illustrating this meaning is from 1849.

Comment: It's worth adding that *both* meanings are in use in the U.S., which can lead to considerable confusion. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_%28parliamentary_procedure%29