# Words that have opposing definitions?

Tags: meaning, antonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [English words that are their own antonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/english-words-that-are-their-own-antonyms)
>   [What words have opposite meanings in different regions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1999/what-words-have-opposite-meanings-in-different-regions)

---

I was reading a book the other day when the author wrote:

> The contradiction is only apparent.

Meaning it was obvious only at first blush, but that some investigation would show the contradiction *isn't* apparent (the more common definition of the word.)

This got me wondering if there were other words in English that had multiple definitions that are opposites or contradict?

Answer (score 0):

One I like, is "to rent" (or to let) because it's the same in many other languages (including French and Mandarin).  Other well known examples are "to fix" (as in rig the votes).

I found a [list](http://www.suite101.com/external_link.cfm?elink=http://www-personal.umich.edu/~cellis/antagonym.html) on the net for you.