# What words sound like opposites but are synonyms?

Tags: synonyms, meaning

Somewhat related to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19195/words-that-have-opposing-definitions), I am curious to know what words in English would seem to be opposites at first blush but are in fact synonyms?

Immediately I can think of ***flammable*** and ***inflammable***.

Comment: I can't think of another example, but Wikipedia has a little paragraph on `Flammable vs inflammable` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflammable#Linguistics:_Flammable_vs._inflammable

Comment: +1 Interesting question, I'll be looking forward to more answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are not infamous and inflammable the opposite of famous and flammable like incomplete, inactivity, inappropriate and so on?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/why-are-not-infamous-and-inflammable-the-opposite-of-famous-and-flammable-like-in)

Comment: Anything without the prefix `in-` and then the same word with the prefix `in-` would be an answer to this question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- regardless and irregardless (although
  some don't consider irregardless a
  real word)
- bone and debone
- press and depress
- caregiver and caretaker
- ravel and unravel

some related examples in slang. These use the same word, but mean the opposite:

- shit and the shit
- bollocks and the bollocks, or the dog's bollocks
- a bomb and the bomb

Comment: I'll add "privation" and "deprivation" here.

Comment: I'll add **habitable** and **inhabitable** here, too.

Comment: And in nonspecialist usage, referring to the stringed instrument, _bass_ and _contrabass_. As for same word near-opposite meanings, I nominate _sanction_ (approval) and _sanction_ (coercive punishment).

Answer (score 2):

Valuable and invaluable is the only example that comes to mind

http://grammarist.com/usage/invaluable-valuable/

Answer (score 1):

Though they are of different origin, I would go for 'genius' and 'ingenious', perhaps?

I also have some points to raise from previous answers:

Irregardless is most likely from a combination of 'irrespective' and 'regardless', which are synonyms of each other. Therefore 'irregardless' is seen as an erroneous construction by many, as Sam pointed out.

Also, 'ravel' and 'unravel' are not the same. The phrasal verb 'ravel out' is synonymous with 'unravel' but alone, 'ravel' means to complicate, while 'unravel' in that sense would mean 'make clear something that was complicated'.

Comment: Ravel: To become untwisted or unwoven; to be disentangled; to be relieved of intricacy. I've seen it most in connection to fabrics _they tend to ravel_. I would also suggest that words are constantly coming into use by people misusing old words. Eventually, if enough people use it incorrectly, it becomes correct. Language is not a fixed thing.

Comment: I'm not sure what dictionary you are using, Sam. Could you point me to it, please? As I understand, the word is of Germanic origin, 'ravelen' - to tangle. Interestingly, its meaning 'to disentangle' is seen in English earlier than 'to entangle' but still combined with the word 'out'

Comment: Shakespeare: must I rauell out My weau'd-vp follyes (King Richard II - 1593)

Comment: [http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ravel](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ravel)  Ravel seems to be one of those special words that can mean opposite things, e.g. cleave and cleave.

Comment: Thanks for that, Sam. I was hunting myself at the same time and came across several definitions, most of which linked back to Mirriam Webster. With that link in mind, it would appear I have to concede, though with the Caveat that M-W is an AmEng dictionary and I am British. I would hazard to say that this is one of those words on which we differ in usage (assuming you are American?). Nevertheless, it appears that 'ravel' can indeed mean both. Thanks again, Sam.

Comment: I am British by birth, American by upbringing. I found [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=y0Q-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA623&dq=ravel+dictionary&hl=en&ei=2ZOYTe7YFYGCtgeFvcyIDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CFgQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q&f=false) in the Imperial Dictionary of the English Language, published in 1882.

Comment: I assume this is another example where British English moved on and American English retained the older meaning. (Other examples are escaping me at the moment,except Aluminium/Aluminum, but it might make a good question.)

Comment: I'm afraid your link takes me only to a description of the Dictionary in question, not the specific finding. It is based on Noah Webster's 'American Dictionary', so I still suggest that BrEng and AmEng may differ. I do still however agree that both definitions should be accepted.

Comment: Yes, it would be an interesting question, I feel.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this one might be "false friends." The term refers to cases where a word in a foreign language is deceptively similar to one in your native tongue and leads you thus astray. Here the case is a bit different but I could see extending the sense a bit.

Another example in the same class is the word "enervate," where the Latinate prefix (as with "in" in "inflammable") has a meaning that leads the unknowing speaker down the wrong path.

Comment: False friends refers to when two words, each from a different language look the same or similar but mean different things, as you correctly said. But I don't think it's really related to the question, since calling "flammable" and "inflammable" false friends might be misleading, in my opinion. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

What is the term for this phenomenon?  Another one I have heard suggested: Overtone/Undertone.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you think *shameful* and *shameless* are actually synonyms?

It's really interesting to see this pair of words utilizing the commonly known *-ful* and *-less* suffixes.