# ravel: opposite meanings?

Tags: meaning, etymology, antonyms

From the definition found at [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ravel) and elsewhere, it seems that *to ravel* has completely opposite meanings; i.e. it means to unravel, to disentangle as well as to entangle.

What's going on here?

Comment: reminds me of the verb 'to cleave', meaning both to stick together and to cut in half

Comment: I remember reading about 45 years ago that 'ravel' and 'unravel' meant the same thing. I had never heard 'ravel' used then, and I don't believe I ever have since. Is it an American thing?

Comment: @Claudiu: *cleave* and *cleave* are actually two different verbs that happen to be spelled the same in contemporary English. The "stick together" *cleave* comes from Old English *clifian* and is related to *clay*, while the "cut in half" *cleave* comes from Old English *cleofan* and is related to *glyph*. (This is quite different from *ravel*, which is actually *one* word with two contradictory meanings.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Etymonline [to the rescue](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ravel):

> 1580s, "to untangle, unwind," also "to become tangled or confused," from Du. *ravelen* "to tangle, fray, unweave," from *rafel* "frayed thread." The seemingly contradictory senses of this word (*ravel* and *unravel* are both synonyms and antonyms) are reconciled by its roots in weaving and sewing: as threads become unwoven, they get tangled.

See also this related question: [English words that are their own antonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/english-words-that-are-their-own-antonyms).