# that's some good sh*t

Tags: slang, offensive-language

I found a web site called http://shitformakingwebsites.com/ to find **excellent-quality** materials for work.

I started wondering why "sh*t" can be used so positively here.  I have a similar question about "nigga".

Comment: Not to mention *Badass*. It's often the case that groups hostile to other social groups that condemn them use the words of condemnation themselves as ingroup solidarity markers. Perfectly normal development.

Comment: See also [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/why-the-opposite-meanings-of-the-word-bollocks).

Comment: @JohnLawler I would've thought that *bad* (meaning good) and 'ass constructions' (yikes - things like *nice-ass car*) both predate *badass* ... I'm not sure where I'm going with this, but it's probably a different question-post.

Answer (score 1):

[Cheech and Chong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheech_&_Chong#Filmography) used the term ["Good Shit" in their drug move "Up in Smoke"](http://movie-sounds.org/comedy-movie-sounds/cheech-and-chong-s-up-in-smoke/good-shit) (1978). The usage in drug subculture predates that.
Good shit goes back to the early 1950's w respect to heroin quality: [new Partridge dictionary of slang and unconventional English](http://books.google.com/books?id=mAdUqLrKw4YC&pg=PA1718&lpg=PA1718&dq=%22good%20shit%22%20lenny%20bruce&source=bl&ots=t1R58JlmAC&sig=3e41jvk-8c0_7BpzNb1gAIsuiAY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mQ3eUdTOOsWHqQGc0IDoDA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22good%20shit%22%20lenny%20bruce&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

While the info about solidarity markers and bollocks is true and relevant to the long-since-completed meaning acquisition, I think in the case of "shit for making websites," it's simply a matter of the *shit* being used to mean *stuff*. At the risk of wielding too sharp a razor, don't think it's any more complicated than that.

For the "nigga" question, consider John Lawler's solidarity comment and the discussion at Brian Hooper's link.

Answer (score 1):

Words often change their meaning, particularly slang. See for example this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22293/how-and-why-have-some-words-changed-to-a-complete-opposite).

### Routledge

*[The Routledge Dictionary of Modern American Slang and Unconventional English](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=neVBmSyNRnEC&pg=PA863&dq=%22good%20shit%22%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MPzeUZmZIpHW4ASr6oCgDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22good%20shit%22&f=false)* (2013) has 14 definitions for the noun *shit*, the first three being marijuana (1946), heroin (1950), and narcotics/drugs in general (1967).

The earliest quotation using *good shit* is about heroin:

> It's good shit, not like some of the stuff we've been getting lately. -- Alexander Trocchi, *Cain's Book*, p. 9, 1960

The next three definitions show its use becoming even more generalised: things/possessions (1969), anything at all (1995), et cetera (1999). All these seven are US.

### Oxford

The *Oxford English Dictionary* lumps the drugs definitions together:

> 5. Any of several intoxicating or narcotic drugs, spec. heroin or marijuana.
>   Used with reference to a specific drug, according to context, not in relation to drugs in general.