# What is the term for words that can be used as the opposite of themselves?

Tags: terminology, antonyms

What is the term for words that can be used as the opposite of themselves?

I know there are a few of them out there, it is possible to 'Dust a cake with Icing' and if the cake were on a shelf for a long time (must be a bad bakery) then it would be acceptable to 'Dust the cake' to remove any dust particles...

In this case, 'Dust with Icing' implies the addition of something to the cake where 'Dust the cake' implies the action of removing dust from the cake

Other examples:

Bolt - To hold in place or to Run away with haste...
Trim - To remove a small portion or to add small bits that make it pretty...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "opposing" or add another example. I'm not seeing how the two meanings of "to dust" are opposing actions.

Comment: Will make some edits now

Comment: I do not think the actions you described are necessarily opposing. Those words simply have multiple meanings. I'm not sure if there's a special word for this. Of course, there's *innuendo* and *double entendre* but that's for a word that has dual meaning, the undertone usually referencing something inappropriate.

Comment: I think *dust* is different from your other examples.  The interesting thing about *dust* used in that sense is that the word *de-dust* would also mean "to remove dust".  Another example is the verb *bone* that means "to remove the bones", which is identical to *debone*.  There's also *loosen* and *unloosen*.  (I've also seen examples like *flammable/inflammable* but that one isn't the *in-* for negation, but rather the *in* like "in flames", so it is just a misunderstanding, and not a "true" contradiction.)  I have no idea if this phenomenon has an official name.

Comment: Interesting point about the de-dust, perhaps that is actually more technically correct to use...

Comment: Duplicate of [English words that are their own antonyms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/), which even mentions *dust*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an *[autoantonym](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autoantonym)*, which has a number of variants enumerated on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoantonym).

Someone coined *[antagonym](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~cellis/antagonym.html)* in 1999.

Comment: Thanks, was an interesting read... I may not have expressed myself to well but this is definitely what I was trying to find out.

Comment: +1 It's always gratifying to see the desired answer turn up every time!