# Word meaning contradiction with itself

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [English words that are their own antonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/english-words-that-are-their-own-antonyms)

What is a word that is a contradiction of itself? I googled this and I got "paradox", but [paradox means:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox)

> A paradox is a seemingly true statement or group of statements that lead to a contradiction or a situation which seems to defy logic or intuition.

What I am actually looking for is a word that actually has two different meanings. This came up while I looked up the meaning of the word "scan", and I found out that it had [several meanings:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scan)

> –verb (used with object)
>   1.
>   to glance at or over or read hastily: to scan a page.
>   2.
>   to examine the particulars or points of minutely; scrutinize.

I realized that there was a term for this, but I couldn't quite remember.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What are the sources for these quotes?

Comment: @Reg, Sir, this isn't a duplicate. That question was asking for a *list* of English words that are their own contradiction. I am asking the *name* of English words that are their own contradiction.

Comment: Question: "Also, what are such words most commonly called? I like the term 'Janus word' I once heard, but is that widely understood?"  Top answer: "I think you're referring to Auto-antonyms. They are not the same word but a homograph (a word of the same spelling) that is also an antonym. I guess, Janus word is also acceptable."

Comment: Thanks! Why didn't you answer, instead of closing it?

Comment: The link that Reg gave also gave autoantonym. So it really is a duplicate of your question.

Comment: The answer to the title question (which has nothing to do with separate meanings) is *oxymoron*.