# Is the term "antagonym" widely used to describe a word that is its own antonym?

Tags: meaning, history

There are several words which have contradictory meanings. They may have one meaning now, and have had a different meaning in the past. For example, the current definition of [*peruse*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peruse) is:

> to look over or through in a casual or cursory manner

However, the older definition (which is still included in the Merriam Webster entry) is:

> to examine or consider with attention and in detail

Is there a name for these pairs of words which have contradictory meanings? One site names them [antagonyms](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~cellis/antagonym.html#derivation), but is this widely known and used? Or is there another term?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [English words that are their own antonyms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/).

Comment: @Reg Noted. In this case, do you have any ideas to make my question distinct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only term I'd heard for these was *contronym*.  [This site](http://www.rinkworks.com/words/contronyms.shtml) lists both as neologisms for this type of word, but notes that no more established term exists.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it gave "contronym", which led me to be able to find even more terms and information about the phenomena. Please see my self-answer for other terms.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the answer left by @Dusty, I was led to the [following terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) for this phenomenon in a Wikipedia article. None are long-established terms, but the list for reference is:

> - auto-antonym
> - Janus word
> - enantiodrome
> - self-antonym
> - antilogy
> - addad

These terms are all fairly recent, as the Wikipedia article continues:

> The terms "autantonym" and "contronym" were originally coined by Joseph T. Shipley in 1960 and Jack Herring in 1962, respectively. A related term, pseudo-contronym, was coined by David Morice in 1987.

Comment: +1: Nice answer to your own question! You *are* a self-learner.

Answer (score 1):

This comic is extremely relevant:

http://www.qwantz.com/index.php?comic=1104

It proposes:

"Homographic Homophonic Autantonyms"