# Words like 'disgruntled' with no positive counterpart

Tags: vocabulary, negation

"I was thoroughly gruntled."

Are there many words like 'disgruntled' where there is no positive counterpart? And was there ever a word 'gruntled'? And if not, where did 'disgruntled' derive from?

Comment: Just as a note, **gruntled** can actually be used in a somewhat humorous way, so you could very well encounter it in an act for example. [Gruntled wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gruntled).

Comment: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/dont-worry-be-gruntled

Comment: @MadWard yes, "gruntled" exists as a **back formation**, but according to that link i posted it was a real word, hundreds of years ago.

Comment: So 'gruntled' is reverse-engineered from 'disgruntled', and apparently by a mistaken process (since Max Williams' source points out 'dis' is not a negative but an intensifier). This raises the risk of someone saying, "I was not feeling gruntled"…but then, it seems P. G. Wodehouse did something similar already.

Comment: See "lost positives" [here](http://www.headbloom.com/index.php/resources/post/disgruntled_uncouth_and_inept/).  Be sure to click through to the [New Yorker bit](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1994/07/25/how-i-met-my-wife). :-)

Comment: 'imitable', 'requited', 'mistakable', 'couth', 'furl', 'array', 'bridled'--all surely uncontroversial words. And 'unsung' hardly seems like a 'lost positive' either. I think that list needs editing.

Comment: 'Mitigating circumstances,' 'committal hearing'--'this is mitigated by the prior events'--sure, 'mitigated' here is a verb, whereas 'unmitigated' is an adjective, but close enough.

Comment: @Dunsanist: yes, the list there is clearly a bit off.  I mainly like it for the article in The New Yorker.

Comment: There are a number of [antonyms for disgruntled](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/disgruntled).  And if you'd bothered to look at the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=disgruntle&allowed_in_frame=0) you'd understand how the word got the way it is.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: @Hot Licks, I wasn't after an antonym. I was after the word that the prefix seemed to imply, the original positive--'un-disgruntled'. And for my next, on-topic question-- What's another word for 'cat'?

Comment: Sarcasm intended by the question above, in case you missed it.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you asked the question, vs just checking the etymology of the word.

Comment: @Hot Licks "Are there many words like 'disgruntled' where there is no positive counterpart?" This question, you mean? I think Max Williams and tore answered it.

Comment: You mean are there words without exact antonyms?  I'm sure there are many.  Or do you mean why is "inject" not the antonym of "abject"?  Because they are both English words.

Comment: No, I mean words that appear to have prefixes making them the negative of another word, where that other word seemingly doesn't exist. Eg. 'antagonist' where 'agonist' doesn't exist (except, of course, that 'agonist' does exist, at least in medical terminology).

Answer (score 2):

For questions like this try http://www.etymonline.com first.
In the case it [shows](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=disgruntle)

> 1680s, from dis- "entirely, very" + obsolete gruntle "to grumble" (Middle English gruntelen, early 15c.), frequentative of grunt (v.).

**EDIT**: And taking a quote from @max-williams's [link](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/dont-worry-be-gruntled),

> [...] instead of being negative, the **“dis-”** prefix in “disgruntled” is an intensifier. It means “utterly” or “completely” and adds emphasis to the root.

Comment: It seems odd that 'dis' could work as both a negator and an intensifier. Those are two opposite functions. Hence the confusion leading to 'gruntled' as a positive.

Comment: Agree. Reminds me of **nonplussed** which is equally messed up. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60869/nonplussed-defines-its-own-antonym

Comment: @k1eran: Two more self-antonyms, just for fun: *cleave* (disambiguate with *apart* or *to*), and *moot point* (less of a self-antonym, but a *moot point* is one discussed at a meeting, but also one not to be discussed any more as it has become trivial or irrelevant).