# What is a word with two synonyms that are antonyms (other than cleave)

Tags: synonyms, antonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone provide me with a list of English words that are their own antonyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/can-anyone-provide-me-with-a-list-of-english-words-that-are-their-own-antonyms)

My wife read on a trivia website that there is only one word in the English language which has two synonyms that are antonyms. The word was cleave, which has the synonyms adhere and separate.

I find this hard to believe given the large number of English words, and the large number of loan words from other languages in usage, and the large number of definitions for each word.

Does anyone else know of a words that have synonyms that are also antonyms?